# Delphi: How to give variables as parameter in a cmd command

Tags: delphi, variables, cmd, parameters, command

Instead of passing a number as parameter. I want to pass a variable for the IP-address. How can I do this?
I've already tried the + operator but it didnt worked.

```
ShellExecute(
    Application.handle, 
    'open', 
    'cmd.exe', 
    PChar('/c "mysqldump -h 192.168.100.1 -uroot database table > C:/Users/user1/Desktop/export.sql"'), 
    nil, 
    SW_show
);
```

Comment: `+` operator definitely works for **string** concatenation.

Comment: Would make far more sense to use CreateProcess, the right tool for the job

Comment: "it didn't worked" is not a useful problem description.  Surely you can do better than that?

Answer (score 1):

If I've correctly understood your question, you are looking for something to compose the command string using variables.
You can do that in several ways, this is one (Using the [`Format`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Tokyo/en/System.SysUtils.Format) function):

```
var
  IPAddress : string;
begin
  IPAddress := '192.168.100.1';

  ShellExecute(
    Application.Handle,
    'open',
    'cmd.exe',
    PChar(Format('/c "mysqldump -h %s -uroot database table > C:/Users/user1/Desktop/export.sql"', [IPAddress])),
    nil,
    SW_SHOW
  );
end;
```

Comment: @coder007: Ok, let us know and [accept the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) if it helped

Comment: I've put a string in PChar. But it still dont work. ShellExecute(Application.handle, 'open', 'cmd.exe',
      PChar(string), nil, SW_show);

Comment: @coder007 please edit your question to include the code that does not work for you. How are you building up the `string` that you pass?

Comment: The only answer to "it still dont work" is "fit what dont work".